# sudo apt install binutils throws not found 404

Tags: apt, updates

Using WSL on Windows and when trying to execute sudo apt install binutils, I see 404 error and install aborts.

```
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 binutils-common amd64 2.30-21ubuntu1~18.04.1 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.31 80]


Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libbinutils amd64 2.30-21ubuntu1~18.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.31 80]
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get update` before trying to install.  Likely outdated archive/version information and an update call will get it available again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the package list is outdated. Run the command

```
sudo apt update
```

---

If update fails, open `/etc/apt/sources.list`and remove the line that reads

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu main universe restricted multiverse
```

Then run `sudo apt update`. There should be no errors now.